# Why are chef attributes being applied or ignored?

Tags: java, tomcat, chef-infra

I'm attempting to set up a Chef role to install openjdk-7-jdk and tomcat7. I'm using the OpsCode community cookbooks for [java](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/java) and [tomcat](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/tomcat). By reading the documentation, I believe I need to override `node[:java][:jdk_version]` and `node[:tomcat][:base_version]`.

I've created the [following role JSON file](https://github.com/McPolemic/tomcat_chef_example/blob/master/chef/roles/tomcat7.rb):

```
name "tomcat7"
run_list "recipe[tomcat]"
default_attributes(
    :java => {
        :jdk_version => "7"
    },
    :tomcat => {
        :base_version => "7",
        :java_options => "-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server -Xms1536m -Xmx1536m -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"
    }
)
```

When I attempt to bring up the VM with Vagrant, it errors out with the following (Note that it mentions both **tomcat6** and **tomcat7**):

```
[2013-10-21T14:05:44-04:00] INFO: Processing package[sun-java6-jdk] action purge (java::default line 25)
[2013-10-21T14:05:44-04:00] INFO: Processing package[sun-java6-bin] action purge (java::default line 25)
[2013-10-21T14:05:44-04:00] INFO: Processing package[sun-java6-jre] action purge (java::default line 25)
[2013-10-21T14:05:44-04:00] INFO: Processing package[tomcat7] action install (tomcat::default line 39)
[2013-10-21T14:05:52-04:00] INFO: Processing package[tomcat7-admin] action install (tomcat::default line 39)
[2013-10-21T14:05:53-04:00] INFO: Processing directory[/usr/share/tomcat6/lib/endorsed] action create (tomcat::default line 45)
[2013-10-21T14:05:53-04:00] INFO: directory[/usr/share/tomcat6/lib/endorsed] created directory /usr/share/tomcat6/lib/endorsed
[2013-10-21T14:05:53-04:00] INFO: directory[/usr/share/tomcat6/lib/endorsed] mode changed to 755
[2013-10-21T14:05:53-04:00] INFO: Processing service[tomcat] action enable (tomcat::default line 83)
[2013-10-21T14:05:53-04:00] INFO: Processing service[tomcat] action start (tomcat::default line 83)
[2013-10-21T14:05:53-04:00] INFO: Processing template[/etc/default/tomcat7] action create (tomcat::default line 122)
[2013-10-21T14:05:53-04:00] INFO: template[/etc/default/tomcat7] backed up to /var/chef/backup/etc/default/tomcat7.chef-20131021140553
[2013-10-21T14:05:53-04:00] INFO: template[/etc/default/tomcat7] updated content
[2013-10-21T14:05:53-04:00] INFO: template[/etc/default/tomcat7] owner changed to 0
[2013-10-21T14:05:53-04:00] INFO: template[/etc/default/tomcat7] group changed to 0    [2013-10-21T14:05:53-04:00] INFO: template[/etc/default/tomcat7] mode changed to 644
[2013-10-21T14:05:53-04:00] INFO: Processing template[/etc/tomcat6/server.xml] action create (tomcat::default line 131)

================================================================================
Error executing action `create` on resource 'template[/etc/tomcat6/server.xml]'
================================================================================

Chef::Exceptions::EnclosingDirectoryDoesNotExist
------------------------------------------------
Parent directory /etc/tomcat6 does not exist.

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/tomcat/recipes/default.rb

130:
131: template "#{node["tomcat"]["config_dir"]}/server.xml" do
132:   source "server.xml.erb"
133:   owner "root"
134:   group "root"
135:   mode "0644"
136:   notifies :restart, "service[tomcat]"
137: end
138:

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/tomcat/recipes/default.rb:131:in `from_file'

template("/etc/tomcat6/server.xml") do
  mode "0644"
  retry_delay 2
  path "/etc/tomcat6/server.xml"
  retries 0
  recipe_name "default"
  owner "root"
  source "server.xml.erb"
  action "create"
  cookbook_name :tomcat
  group "root"
  backup 5
  provider Chef::Provider::Template
end

[2013-10-21T14:05:53-04:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2013-10-21T14:05:53-04:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2013-10-21T14:05:53-04:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-stacktrace.out
[2013-10-21T14:05:53-04:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::EnclosingDirectoryDoesNotExist: template[/etc/tomcat6/server.xml] (tomcat::default line 131) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::EnclosingDirectoryDoesNotExist: Parent directory /etc/tomcat6 does not exist.
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

It seems that the `node[:tomcat][:base_version]` attribute is being overridden, as it's installing tomcat7 and tomcat7-admin. However, it is creating tomcat6 directories.

The full example can be found at https://github.com/McPolemic/tomcat_chef_example/.

Is there a rhyme or reason as to when it picks the default or my attributes?

Comment: What version of chef-client/chef-solo are you using?

Comment: I've had the same problem with the java cookbook, the only solution I found was to roll back to version 1.10.0.

Comment: @JaredRussell I was using 10.14.2, which was the default for Vagrant. I've updated to 11.6.2 now, but I'm still seeing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's a bug in the recipe - if you override base_version, in some cases you also need to override config_dir.

Comment: That was what I was missing. I had to end up setting a number of variables, but I did get it running.

Comment: @AdamLukens can you please mention how you fixed it ?